# How to highlight in flex

Tags: apache-flex, text, highlight

In flex, how can I highlight text/label? I have text and a small image that I want to highlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to add a glow filter around the UIComponents you want highlight.

[Glow Filter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform//reference/actionscript/3/flash/filters/GlowFilter.html?allClasses=1)

If you want to highlight part of the text, not so simple, you'll need to work it out in HTML and set the htmlText of the Label.

Comment: I tried <mx:htmlText> inside <mx:Text> but I can apply <font> tag, <b> etc but I cannot use bgcolor or background image. I was thinking about using bgcolor in background togive a solid highlight.

Comment: Here's what you can do with htmlText
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform//reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText
You might want to think about swapping styles for the label and the image to one with a different background colour.